# Can I optionally turn off the JsonIgnore attribute at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I am creating a JSON file with Newtonsoft.Json from a set of classes. The file created is very large, so I have created `JsonProperty`'s for the properties to reduce the size and added `JsonIgnore` and custom formatting for some datatypes.

The result is a reduction from 24MB to 1MB, which is great; however, I'd like the option to produce either the full version or the reduced property version at runtime.

Is there anyway I can get the serializer to optionally use the attributes?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Yes, this can be done using a custom `ContractResolver`.

You didn't show any code, so I'll just make up an example.  Let's say I have a class `Foo` as shown below.  I want the `Id` and `Name` properties in the serialization output, but I'm definitely not interested in the `AlternateName` and `Color`.  I've marked those with `[JsonIgnore]`.  I want the description to appear, but sometimes this can get really long, so I've used a custom `JsonConverter` to limit its length.  I also want to use a shorter property name for the description, so I've marked it with `[JsonProperty("Desc")]`.

```
class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string AlternateName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Desc")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringTruncatingConverter))]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

When I serialize an instance of the above...

```
Foo foo = new Foo
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "Thing 1",
    AlternateName = "The First Thing",
    Description = "This is some lengthy text describing Thing 1 which you'll no doubt find very interesting and useful.",
    Color = "Yellow"
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, Formatting.Indented);
```

...I get this output:

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "Thing 1",
  "Desc": "This is some lengthy text describing Thing 1 "
}
```

Now, let's say that I sometimes want to get the full JSON output, ignoring my customizations.  I can use a custom `ContractResolver` to programmatically "unapply" the attributes from the class.  Here's the code for the resolver:

```
class IgnoreJsonAttributesResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        IList<JsonProperty> props = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            prop.Ignored = false;   // Ignore [JsonIgnore]
            prop.Converter = null;  // Ignore [JsonConverter]
            prop.PropertyName = prop.UnderlyingName;  // restore original property name
        }
        return props;
    }
}
```

To use the resolver, I add it to the `JsonSerializerSettings` and pass the settings to the serializer like this:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.ContractResolver = new IgnoreJsonAttributesResolver();
settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, settings);
```

The output now includes the ignored properties, and the description is no longer truncated:

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "Thing 1",
  "AlternateName": "The First Thing",
  "Description": "This is some lengthy text describing Thing 1 which you'll no doubt find very interesting and useful.",
  "Color": "Yellow"
}
```

Full demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WZpeWt

Comment: Brill answer Brian,  works like a charm, do you know how to turn off the [JsonProperty("ShortName")] attribute?

Comment: Yes, add `prop.PropertyName = prop.UnderlyingName;` inside the loop in the resolver.  This will cause the property to use its original name.

Comment: @BrianRogers great answer. In my scenario I have a graph of objects to convert, for each type in the tree (when implementing a specific type) I need to include/exclude properties according to their values.

Comment: @Shimmy If you have a followup question you should [ask it as a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).  You can include [a link back to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37371786/10263) if it helps provide context.  The comment section is not a good place for questions because comments are limited in both length and formatting; they are not searchable, and they don't appear in the questions list, which means you are much less likely to get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: wrt "Ignore [JsonIgnore]" - the list of props that I get simply doesn't include the props that have [JsonIgnore]

Answer (score -2):

Json support us to ignore property that don't want return.
Example

```
class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string AlternateName { get; set; }    
}
```

How to use it:

```
Foo foo = new Foo
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "Thing 1",
    AlternateName = null,   
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo);
```

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked.

Answer (score -2):

If you are willing to use F# (or simply use an API not optimized for C#), the [FSharp.JsonSkippable](https://github.com/cmeeren/FSharp.JsonSkippable) library contains a generic wrapper type that allows you to control in a simple and strongly typed manner whether to include a given property when serializing (and determine whether a property was included when deserializing), and moreover, to control/determine exclusion separately of nullability. (Full disclosure: I'm the author of the library.)