# JsonIgnore attribute conditional analog but not ShouldSerialize

Tags: c#, json, attributes

I want to implement a conditional version of [JsonIgnore] attribute in C#. I don't want to use ShouldSerializePropertyName due to it's dependency on hardcoded property name.

My API model inherits from the database model and I certainly want to ignore database Ids but I also want to ignore some other properties based on which features the customer payed for. I don't want to use ShouldSerialize technique because the other developers in my team could change the database property name and accidentally make visible what should not be visible.

I read [if I can optionally turn off the JsonIgnore attribute at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37371786/can-i-optionally-turn-off-the-jsonignore-attribute-at-runtime)

but it looks like the suggested technique turns off all JsonIgnore together. What I want to do is to have just some of them off based on some condition.

Is there a work around? Is there some attribute which could do that? If I need to write a custom attribute, could you show me how please? Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want to use a hardcoded method name, what *do* you want to use?  A static method with an attribute-specified name?  An instance method with an attribute-specified name?  Or something entirely runtime that doesn't require adding Json.NET attributes to your type?  Is [Conditional member serialization based on query parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29713847/3744182) what you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an interesting problem.  My answer borrows heavily from the link you provided, but checks for a custom attribute defining your "Premium Content" (things that the user paid for):

Like your link, I have defined a class `Foo`, which will be serialized.  It contains a child object `PremiumStuff`, which contains things that should only be serialized if the user paid for them.  I have marked this child object with a custom attribute `PremiumContent`, which is also defined in this code snippet.  I then used a custom class that inherits from `DefaultContractResolver` just like the link did, but in this implementation, I am checking each property for our custom attribute, and running the code in the `if` block only if the property is marked as `PremiumContent`.  This conditional code checks a static bool called `AllowPremiumContent` to see whether we are allowing the premium content to be serialized.  If it is not allowed, then we are setting the `Ignore` flag to true:

```
class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string AlternateName { get; set; }
    [PremiumContent]
    public PremiumStuff ExtraContent { get; set; }
}

class PremiumStuff
{
    public string ExtraInfo { get; set; }
    public string SecretInfo { get; set; }
}

class IncludePremiumContentAttributesResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        IList<JsonProperty> props = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            if (Attribute.IsDefined(type.GetProperty(prop.PropertyName), typeof(PremiumContent)))
            {
                //if the attribute is marked with [PremiumContent]

                if (PremiumContentRights.AllowPremiumContent == false)
                {
                    prop.Ignored = true;   // Ignore this if PremiumContentRights.AllowPremiumContent is set to false
                }
            }
        }
        return props;
    }
}

[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.All)]
public class PremiumContent : Attribute
{
}

public static class PremiumContentRights
{
    public static bool AllowPremiumContent = true;
}
```

Now, let's implement this and see what we get.  Here is my test code:

```
PremiumContentRights.AllowPremiumContent = true;
Foo foo = new Foo()
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "Hello",
    AlternateName = "World",
    ExtraContent = new PremiumStuff()
    {
        ExtraInfo = "For premium",
        SecretInfo = "users only."
    }
};

JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.ContractResolver = new IncludePremiumContentAttributesResolver();
settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, settings);

Debug.WriteLine(json);
```

In the first line, `PremiumContentRights.AllowPremiumContent` is set to true, and here is the output:

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "Hello",
  "ExtraContent": {
    "ExtraInfo": "For premium",
    "SecretInfo": "users only."
  }
}
```

If we set `AllowPremiumContent` to `False` and run the code again, here is the output:

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "Hello"
}
```

As you can see, the `ExtraContent` property is included or ignored depending on the state of the `AllowPremiumContent` variable.

Comment: You might consider using [`[ThreadStatic]` or `ThreadLocal<bool>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18333885) for your `AllowPremiumContent`.  Asp.net, for instances, shares the same contract resolver across multiple server threads.