# Trying to hide a property in Response, but still get a subproperty of it

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, odata

So I have an MVC application that uses OData for requests to get the right data from the database using Entity Framework Core. Mapping and everything is set. The entities look like this:

```
public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserGroup> UserGroups { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserGroup> UserGroups { get; set; }
}

public class UserGroup
{
    public long UserId{ get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public long GroupId{ get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

My call against it looks something like this:

http://localhost:8080/User(1)?$expand=UserGroups($expand=Group)

So far so good. But what I get back is the `User` entity, a list of `UserGroup` entities and their underlying `Group` entities:

**Current Result:**

```
{
    "UserId": 1,
    "Name": "TestUser",
    "UserGroups": [
        {
            "UserId": 1,
            "GroupId": 45,
            "Group": {
                "GroupId": 45,
                "Name": "Section1Reader"
            }
        },
        {
            "UserId": 1,
            "GroupId": 47,
            "Group": {
                "GroupId": 47,
                "Name": "Section2Writer"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to not get the UserGroup entities, but the Group entities directly:

**Required Result:**

```
{
    "UserId": 1,
    "Name": "TestUser",
    "UserGroups": [
        {
            "GroupId": 45,
            "Name": "Section1Reader"
        },
        {
            "GroupId": 47,
            "Name": "Section2Writer"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Change your object structure?

Answer (score 1):

try doing this:

```
public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserGroup> UserGroups { get; set; }
}

public class UserGroup
{    

    public long GroupId{ get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

for more advance approch see this code https://dotnetfiddle.net/WZpeWt which posted in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37376089/9673980

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work, since MS-SQL does not support referencing whole table entries without a foreign key. That foreign key has to exist somewhere.

Comment: I already tried a JsonConverter. Unfortunately OData seems to just ignore those