# How to save JsonIgnore objects as textblob in Sqlite?

Tags: c#, json, sqlite, xamarin, json.net

I have a strange issue, I have a model class which looks like this

```
public class Person
{
 public string FirstName{get;set;}
 public string LastName{get;set;}
 [JsonIgnore]
 [TextBlob("ApartmentBlobbed")]
 public Apartment Apartment{get;set;}
 [JsonIgnore]
 public string ApartmentBlobbed{get;set;}
 
 public string Exception
 {
    get 
    { 
       return Apartment.Exception;
    }
    set
    {
        Apartment.Exception = value;
    }
 }

}
public class Apartment
{
 public string RoomNumber{get;set;}
 public string BuildingNumber{get;set;}
 public string Exception{get;set;}
}
```

I have a POST API call which only requires **FirstName** and **LastName** of Person object hence I have inserted the attribute **JsonIgnore** for the **Apartment** Object. If there occurs any exception then I need the Apartment object's exception to be set. As it is the same object which is being used in the UI.

Now the problem
Since the API is called at some point in time, the Person object is saved in the database.
When I retrieve the object of Person for API call, my Apartment object is null and hence the exception is also null.

**REASON**: Due to the JsonIgnore being set. SQLite uses NewtonSoft to serialize/Deserialize the objects.

**Question**:

How can I save the object with JsonIgnore and have the API call only with FirstName and LastName values, and if any exception occurs then I can set the Exception to the Apartment Exception.

Comment: It is never a good idea to have a class fulfill more than one aspect (here persistence and presentation). You may reuse it for any other aspect as long as you do not have to change its code. Search for SRP (SingleResponsiblePrinciple)

Comment: Does [Can I optionally turn off the JsonIgnore attribute at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37371786/3744182) answer your question?